# how to get all permutations for bitarray

Tags: c#, .net

how to generate all permutations for bitarray of n size?

I mean for example if array of 1 and 0 has integer type I can do like this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= ~(-1 << n); i++)
   string s = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(n, '0');
```

and s will contain some permutation for example 101010 or 100000 and etc.
So I can get all permutations.
For example for n=3

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

But how to do the same for bitarray?(because I need XOR operations and etc.)

Comment: A permutation is an ordering of a set (usually the set 1, 2, ... n).  So 100000 and 101010 can't be permutations of the same set.  What do you really mean when you use the word permutation?

Comment: What is a 'permutation'? It seems your definition deviates somewhat from the normal definition. Could you please explain the question better?

Comment: 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111

Comment: I think the OP means all possible unique sequences of bits that fit within a given bit length.

Comment: @DrewNoakes I believe you're right.

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов Is there an upper limit on `n`?  There are 4 billion possible bit arrays of 32 bits, which will cause your process to run out of memory unless it's running as a 64-bit process.

Comment: the no upper limit but I think it will be no more than 7 or 8

Answer (score 3):

I don't have VS open right now, but you could use the [`BitArray(byte[])` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xda43a.aspx).

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1 << n; i++)
{
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
    var bitArray = new BitArray(bytes);
}
```

You'll have to experiment and come up with the shifting logic to convert an int into bytes.

If you need greater than 32/64 bits, then you'll obviously need another approach.

Comment: cannot resolve symbol IntToBytes. Or IntToBytes - my own method for converting?and It should return array of bytes?

Comment: `IntToBytes` has been implemented: `BitConverter.GetBytes(int)`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx

Comment: `BitConverter.GetBytes` is a method which converts an `int` into a `byte[]`. As always be careful about endianness with this method. (What order the `byte`s are in)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you work with `int` or `long` , since you will never able to work with permutations larger than ~2^32(in fact much lesser) in a *reasonable* time.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(i,2).PadLeft(6,'0'));
}
```

Output:

```
000000
000001
000010
000011
000100
000101
000110
000111
001000
001001
001010
001011
001100
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is based on a recursive list-filling procedure that I wrote for a recent project.

```
private void GenerateStringsRecursive(List<string> strings, int n, string cur)
{
    if (cur.Length == n)
    {
        strings.Add(cur);
    }
    else
    {
        GenerateStringsRecursive(strings, n, cur + "0");
        GenerateStringsRecursive(strings, n, cur + "1");
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
GenerateStringsRecursive(strings, n, "");
foreach (string s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

I imagine this would be subject to optimizations such as using a `StringBuilder` etc.

Answer (score 1):

A generalised Permute function that will return all the combinations of any enumerable.

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permute<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        for (int i = (1 << list.Count()) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            yield return list.BitWhere(i);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> BitWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int selector)
    {
        BitVector32 bits = new BitVector32(selector);
        int c = list.Count();
        for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++)
        {
            if (bits[1 << (c - i)])
                yield return list.ElementAt(i - 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BigInteger for this task.
It is essentially a bit array with arithmetic operations, so you can permute the bits by adding one, as you already can do with Int32 and Int64 integers.

At the same time, BigInteger supports bit arithmetics, so you can do xor with ^ operator.